# Check if string matches pattern

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

How do I check if a string matches the following pattern?

Uppercase letter, number(s), uppercase letter, number(s)...

Example:

- These would match:

  ```
  A1B2
  B10L1
  C1N200J1
  ```
- These wouldn't ('^' points to problem)

  ```
  a1B2
  ^
  A10B
     ^
  AB400
  ^
  ```

Comment: could you please explain more why it is a problem?

Comment: `^([A-Z]\d+){1,}$` like this?

Comment: In your third example, the problem should be with `B` and not with `A`.

Comment: maybe it's a typo error on the problem. both `A` and `B` are small letters right? `A10b` and `aB400`?

Comment: @Burhan, The problem is with A because B has numbers next to it and A doesn't

Answer (score 702, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("^([A-Z][0-9]+)+$")
pattern.match(string)
```

Comment: From the docs on `re.match`: `If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern`. I just spent like 30 minutes trying to understand why I couldn't match something at the end of a string. Seems like it's not possible with `match`, is it? For that, `re.search(pattern, my_string)` works though.

Comment: @conradk Yes, you're right, I think there's something like an implied `^` at the beginning when you use `match`. I think it's a bit more complicated then that very simple explanation, but I'm not clear. You are correct that it does start from the beginning of the string though.

Comment: I edited your answer, because it only makes sense with `search()` in this context.

Comment: Yes, but that's what the questioner wants. I'm not sure what you mean by "only makes sense with `search()`". It works perfectly fine with match.

Comment: To be clear: You probably want to check if pattern.match returns something; luckily "None" is truthy, so you can just do "if pattern.match:"

Answer (score 388):

**One-liner: `re.match(r"pattern", string) # No need to compile`**

```
import re
>>> if re.match(r"hello[0-9]+", 'hello1'):
...     print('Yes')
... 
Yes
```

You can evaluate it as `bool` if needed

```
>>> bool(re.match(r"hello[0-9]+", 'hello1'))
True
```

Comment: That's weird. Why can you use `re.match` in the context of an `if`, but you have to use `bool` if you're using it elsewhere?

Comment: Careful with `re.match`. It only matches at the start of a string. Have a look at `re.search` instead.

Comment: @LondonRob probably because `if` checks for the match not being `None`.

Comment: There's a big need to compile to make sure there are no errors in the regular expressions like bad character range errors

Comment: @SuhFangmbeng Compilation is useful when the same `re` is used in more than one places to improve efficiency. In terms of error `.match` would throw the same error what `.compile` does. It's perfectly safe to use.

Comment: @nehem actually all of the regex functions in `re` module compile and cache the patterns. Therefore there is absolutely no efficiency gain using compile and then match than just directly calling `re.match`. All of these functions call the internal function `_compile` (including `re.compile`) which does the caching to a python dictionary.

Comment: If you're in python 3.8+ you can use the walrus operator if you need to access the match object: 
```if (match := re.match(r"hello([0-9]+)", string)): print(match[1])```

Answer (score 58):

Please try the following:

```
import re

name = ["A1B1", "djdd", "B2C4", "C2H2", "jdoi","1A4V"]

# Match names.
for element in name:
     m = re.match("(^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d)", element)
     if m:
        print(m.groups())
```

Comment: This is the only case that returns the match which is required for getting groups.  Best answer in my opinion.

Comment: best answer among other answers

Answer (score 31):

```
import re
import sys

prog = re.compile('([A-Z]\d+)+')

while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if not line: break

  if prog.match(line):
    print 'matched'
  else:
    print 'not matched'
```

Answer (score 24):

#### Careful! (Maybe you want to check if FULL string matches)

The `re.match(...)` will not work if you want to match the full string.

For example;

- `re.match("[a-z]+", "abcdef")` ✅ will give a match
- But! `re.match("[a-z]+", "abcdef 12345")` ✅ will also give a match because there is a part in string which matches (maybe you don't want that when you're checking if the entire string is valid or not)

## Solution

Use `re.fullmatch(...)`. This will only match if the

```
if re.fullmatch("[a-z]+", my_string):
    print("Yes")
```

###### Example

- `re.fullmatch("[a-z]+", "abcdef")` ✅ Yes
- `re.fullmatch("[a-z]+", "abcdef 12345")` ❌ No

**One liner:** `bool(re.fullmatch("[a-z]+", my_string))`

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted to see for "check if string matches"

Answer (score 22):

As stated in the comments, all these answers using `re.match` implicitly matches on the start of the string. `re.search` is needed if you want to generalize to the whole string.

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile("([A-Z][0-9]+)+")

# finds match anywhere in string
bool(re.search(pattern, 'aA1A1'))  # True

# matches on start of string, even though pattern does not have ^ constraint
bool(re.match(pattern, 'aA1A1'))  # False
```

If you need the full string to exactly match the regex, see @Ali Sajjad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398901/4212158) using `re.fullmatch`

Credit: @LondonRob and @conradkleinespel in the comments.

Answer (score 13):

regular expressions make this easy ...

`[A-Z]` will match exactly one character between A and Z

`\d+` will match one or more digits

`()` group things (and also return things... but for now just think of them grouping)

`+` selects 1 or more

Answer (score 12):

```
  
import re

ab = re.compile("^([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})+$")
ab.match(string)
```

I believe that should work for an **uppercase, number** pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out that for string without line breaks (`\n`), one could also use the anchors `\A` and `\Z` for beginning and end of a string, respectively.

```py
import re
pat = re.compile(r'\A([A-Z][0-9]+)+\Z')
pat.match('A1B2')   # match
pat.match('A1B2a')  # no match
```

This makes a difference if the string contains multiple lines and you want to match the pattern in latter lines in a string.

##### `match` vs `search` vs `fullmatch`. Which is appropriate?

`re.search` is the more general of the three. As others have said, `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string. `re.search()` can mimic that too by prepending `\A` to whatever pattern used. On the other hand, `re.fullmatch()` checks if the entire string is a match, which can again be mimicked by `re.search()` by prepending `\A` and appending `\Z` to whatever pattern used. Below example may help illustrate this point.

```py
# prepending \A to pattern makes `search` behave similar to `match`
s1 = '1B10L1'
pattern1 = r'([A-Z][0-9]+)+'

re.match(pattern1, s1)             # no match
re.search(pattern1, s1)            # match
re.search(fr"\A{pattern1}", s1)    # no match     <--- with \A prepended (behaves same as re.match)


# `match` only checks at the beginning and doesn't care about the end of the string
s2 = 'B10L1a'

re.match(pattern1, s2)             # match
re.match(fr"{pattern1}\Z", s2)     # no match     <--- with \Z appended (behaves same as re.fullmatch)
re.search(fr"\A{pattern1}\Z", s2)  # no match     <--- have the pattern between \A and \Z to mimic fullmatch
re.fullmatch(pattern1, s2)         # no match
```

If the string contains multiple lines and if it's flagged, then this relation breaks down: `fullmatch` never scans across lines and `match` scans only the first line.

```py
# by flagging multiline, `match` and `search` match the pattern in the first line
s3 = 'B10\nL1'
pattern2 = r'^([A-Z][0-9]+)+$'
re.match(pattern2, s3, re.M)       # match
re.search(pattern2, s3, re.M)      # match
re.fullmatch(pattern2, s3, re.M)   # no match

# the pattern is in the second line but this will not be matched by `match`
s4 = 'a\nB10'
pattern2 = r'^([A-Z][0-9]+)+$'

re.match(pattern2, s4, re.M)              # no match
re.search(pattern2, s4, re.M)             # match
re.search(r'\A([A-Z][0-9]+)+', s4, re.M)  # no match  <--- with `\A` instead of `^` it mimics `match`
```

##### To compile or not to compile

If you need to search a pattern in a single string, then there's no need to compile it since `re.search`, `re.match` etc. all make calls to `_compile` method anyway. However, if you need to search a pattern in multiple strings, then compiling it first makes a lot of difference performance-wise. For the example in the OP, pre-compiling the pattern and searching through the list is over 2 times faster than not compiling first.

```py
from timeit import timeit
setup2 = "import re; lst = ['A1B2', 'B10L1', 'C1N200J1K1', 'a1B2', 'A10B', 'AB400']"
setup1 = setup2 + "; pat = re.compile(r'^([A-Z][0-9]+)+$')"

for _ in range(3):
    t1 = timeit("list(map(pat.match, lst))", setup1)         # pre-compiled
    t2 = timeit("[re.match(r'^([A-Z][0-9]+)+$', x) for x in lst]", setup2)
    print(t2 / t1)
    
# 2.083788080189313
# 2.448126223007598
# 2.43617482049811
```

Comment: I find the beginning of your answer confusing. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519405/4284627), `\A` mimics `match` regardless of whether there are line breaks or not. Neither `\A` nor `match` care about line breaks. If you want to match the pattern in later lines, you need to use `^` together with the `re.M` option.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I merely meant to say that when `\A` and `\Z` are used together, it can match a pattern in a single line string, so the pattern in that example matches `'A1B2'` but doesn't match `'A1\nB2'`.

Answer (score 0):

[Ali Sajjad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398901/595305) should be the default, i.e. `fullmatch` to avoid false positives.

However, it's also important to know that you're always checking `not None` for "yes, it's a match":

The two possibilities are therefore:

`if re.fullmatch("[a-z]+", my_string)!=None:`

or, as in Ali's answer:

`if bool(re.fullmatch("[a-z]+", my_string)):`

To my way of thinking both of these are really quite horribly unreadable. So a simple utility function is needed for readability:

```
def is_match(pattern, string, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL): # or "is_full_match", as desired
    return re.fullmatch(pattern, string, flags)!=None
```

Those 2 flags are (usually) the most helpful default `flags` settings in my experience, rather than "0".

In practice, of course, you may need to examine the `Match` object delivered by `re.fullmatch`. But for cases where you just need to find whether there's a match...