# How to match exact strings and wildcard strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, wildcard, string-matching, discord.py

Say for example I have this:

```
import discord, asyncio, time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!test"):
        await client.send_message(message.channel,'test')

client.run('clienttokenhere')
```

I would like to do be able to to do 2 things:

1) Make it so that if and only if the user types in *exactly* `!test` and nothing else, it will print out `test` in the channel

2) Make it so that if the user types in `!test` first followed by a space  and at least one other string character, it wlll print out `test` -- so for examples: a) `!test` will not print out anything, b) `!test`  (`!test` followed by a single space) will not print out anything, c) `!test1` will not print out anything, d) `!testabc` will not print out anything, but e) `!test 1` will print out `test`, f) `!test 123abc` will print out `test`, g) `!test a` will print out `test`, and h) `!test ?!abc123` will print out `test`, etc.

I only know of `startswith` and `endswith`, and far as my research tells, there's no such thing as `exact` and I'm not sure how to make it so that it requires a minimum number characters after a `startswith`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string matches pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595051/check-if-string-matches-pattern)

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `==` operator.

1) Print test when there's only `!test` in the received string

```
if message.content.lower() == '!test':
    await client.send_message(message.channel,'test')
```

2) Print `test` followed by the string when it's followed by a string

```
# If it starts with !test and a space, and the length of a list
# separated by a space containing only non-empty strings is larger than 1,
# print the string without the first word (which is !test)

if message.content.lower().startswith("!test ") 
   and len([x for x in message.content.lower().split(' ') if x]) > 1:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'test ' + ' '.join(message.content.split(' ')[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a regular expression instead of `startswith()`. And you appear to have two conflicting requirements:

1) Make it so that if and only if the user types in exactly `!test` and nothing else, it will print out `test` in the channel

2a) `!test` will not print out anything

Including 1 and excluding 2a:

```
import re
test_re = re.compile(r"!test( \S+)?$")
# This says: look for
# !test (optionally followed by one space followed by one or more nonspace chars) followed by EOL
# 

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if test_re.match(message.content.lower()):
        await client.send_message(message.channel,'test')
```

Including 2a and excluding 1, substitute this line (the space and stuff after `!test` is no longer optional):

```
test_re = re.compile(r"!test \S+$")
```