# How to use RegEx in an if statement in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing something like "Syntax Analyzer" with `Kivy`, using `re` (regular expresions).

I only want to check a valid syntax for basic operations (like +|-|*|/|(|)).
The user tape the string (with keyboard) and I validate it with regex.
But I don't know how to use regex in an if statement. That I want is: If the string that user brings me isn't correct (or doesn't check with regex) print something like "inavlid string" and if is correct print "Valid string".

I've tried with:

```
if re.match(patron, string) is not None:
    print ("\nTrue")
else:
    print("False")
```

but, it doesn't matter what do `string` has, the app always show `True`.

Sorry my poor english. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import  re

patron= re.compile(r"""

    (
    -?\d+[.\d+]?
    [+*-/]
    -?\d+[.\d+]?
    [+|-|*|/]?
    )*
    """, re.X)

obj1= self.ids['text'].text #TextInput
if re.match(patron, obj1) is not None:
    print ("\nValid String")
else:
    print("Inavlid string")
```

`if obj1= "53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66"` actually it's correct and app prints "Valid..." but if I put an `a` like this `"a53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66"` it's incorrect and the app must prints `invalid..` but instead it still `valid`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string matches pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595051/check-if-string-matches-pattern)

Comment: the kivy tag is irrelevant in this case, you are validating a string, and the kivy string is the native python string.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Kudos for a well-written question that contains a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex always matches because it allows the empty string to match (since the entire regex is enclosed in an optional group.

If you test this [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/750sOO/1), you can immediately see this and also that it doesn't match the entire string but only parts of it.

I've already corrected two errors in your [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) concerning the use of unnecessary/harmful alternation operators (`|`) and incorrect placement of the dash, making it into a range operator (`-`), but it's still incorrect.

I *think* you want something more like this:

```
^               # Make sure the match begins at the start of the string
(?:             # Start a non-capturing group that matches...
    -?          # an optional minus sign,
    \d+         # one or more digits
    (?:\.\d+)?  # an optional group that contains a dot and one or more digits.
    (?:         # Start of a non-capturing group that either matches...
       [+*/-]   # an operator
    |           # or
       $        # the end of the string.
    )           # End of inner non-capturing group
)+              # End of outer non-capturing group, required to match at least once.
(?<![+*/-])     # Make sure that the final character isn't an operator.
$               # Make sure that the match ends at the end of the string.
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/750sOO/4).

Comment: You man @Tim Pietzcker are the best. I dind't know that syntax (?: xx )? to do something optional. I've modified the '+' to '*' 'cause my app can accept an empty string... now I'm trying to add '(' ')' to do operation inside them, but I can't do it.
I've tried something like:
 ^
(?:
    -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
    (?:[+*/-]|$)
    (?:\(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[+*/-]|\))\))?
)+
$
[link]https://regex101.com/r/750sOO/5 
But doesn't work. Can you help me? Just need '(n (+|-|*|/) m)' Thanks a lot

Comment: As soon as you use parentheses (especially since they can be arbitrarily nested), you're leaving the realm of regular expressions. Python regexes can't recurse or count opening/closing parentheses. You need a context-free grammar/parser for that.

Answer (score 0):

This answers your question about how to use if with regex:
***Caveat**: the regex formula will not weed out all invalid inputs, e.g., two decimal points (".."), two operators ("++"), and such.  So please adjust it to suit your exact needs)*

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"[\d.+\-*\/]+")

input_list = [
    "53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66", "a53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66",
    "53.22+22.pq11+10*555+62+55.2-66", "53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66zz",
]

for input_str in input_list:
    mmm = regex.match(input_str)
    if mmm and input_str == mmm.group():
        print('Valid: ', input_str)
    else:
        print('Invalid: ', input_str)
```

Above as a function for use with a single string instead of a list:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"[\d.+\-*\/]+")

def check_for_valid_string(in_string=""):
    mmm = regex.match(in_string)
    if mmm and in_string == mmm.group():
        return 'Valid: ', in_string
    return 'Invalid: ', in_string

check_for_valid_string('53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66')
check_for_valid_string('a53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66')
check_for_valid_string('53.22+22.pq11+10*555+62+55.2-66')
check_for_valid_string('53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66zz')
```

Output:

```
## Valid:  53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66
## Invalid:  a53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66
## Invalid:  53.22+22.pq11+10*555+62+55.2-66
## Invalid:  53.22+22.11+10*555+62+55.2-66zz
```