# How to do negate search using regex in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

```
re.search('python', 'Working on python is easy')
```

Here I am able to search python.

I want negative pattern to be placed which actually should result nothing or no match.

I like to use re.search when string contains python but doesn't contain easy in string 'Working on python is easy'. How would I do that? Both positive and negative condition at the same time.

Comment: May be this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: What's wrong with `not re.search(...)`?

Comment: I like to use re.search when string contains python but doesn't contain easy in string 'Working on python is easy'. How would I do that? Both positive and negative condition at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `if statement` so that the match `object`  only return `True` if `easy` is not given.

For example :

```
import re
if re.search('python', 'Working on python is easy') and not re.search('easy', 'Working on python is easy'):
    print("found a match")
```

Some **additional sources** which may help you:

[Python: How to use RegEx in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225608/python-how-to-use-regex-in-an-if-statement)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects

[How to use RegEx in an if statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525453/how-to-use-regex-in-an-if-statement-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want with if condition as I will have list of patterns. some will have only positive search and some may have both positive and negative search and that can also have multiple strings to be searched and not to be searched. So if condition i think, will not work.

Comment: I think it will, you may have to put that than a bit more precise in your question. It could work in combination with lists. But now **please specify your question**.