# How to convert my code having startswith using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have dict and need to extract the value starts with '12'. I have wrote the code and working. Can help me writing the code with regex

```
test = {'name': 'a','num': '1234','num2':'5678', 'num3':'0142'}
[ k for k,v in test.items() if str(v).startswith('12')]
```

My Out

```
['num', 'num4']
```

Comment: [Check if string matches pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595051/check-if-string-matches-pattern)

Comment: Why do you need to use regex when `startswith` is already doing the job? In what way is it insufficient for your needs (please provide a variety of input and output examples and explain what you need to achieve). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

test = {'name': 'a', 'num': '1234', 'num2': '5678', 'num3': '0142'}
[k for k, v in test.items() if re.match('12', v)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code also works fine. You are printing key instead of value.

```
test = {'name': 'a','num': '1234','num2':'5678', 'num3':'0142'}
[ v for k,v in test.items() if str(v).startswith('12')]
```

Output:

```
['1234']
```