# Python CSV Regex All Columns And Output Column List Index Number Based On Most Regex Matches

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey I'm really stuck and I really hope someone can help me with this. I'm trying to read the first 5000 lines of a CSV file, split the lines by tab delimiter, then search a regex pattern against every column and line, and output the column index number with the most regex matches/occurrences. I will provide an example to help better explain what i mean.

**test.csv**

```
john smith  1132 Anywhere Lane Hoboken NJ   10.0.0.1     07030  Jan 4
erica meyers    1234 Smith Lane Hoboken NJ  127.0.0.1    07030  March 2
erica meyers    1234 Smith Lane Hoboken NJ  192.168.1.1  07030  april 5
```

This is where I am currently at (read csv, separate into columns by tab delimiter, print first 100 lines ):

```
import csv
import re
        
Num = 5000
        
with open('test.csv', newline='', encoding="cp437", errors='ignore') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for i in range(Num):
        lines = next(reader)
```

First few lines of current output:

```
['john smith', '1132 Anywhere Lane Hoboken NJ', '10.0.0.1', ' 07030', 'Jan 4']
['john smith', '1234 Smith Lane Hoboken NJ', '127.0.0.1', ' 07030', 'March 2']
['smith john', '1234 Smith Lane Hoboken NJ', '192.168.1.1', ' 07030', 'april 5']
```

here is where i am stuck...

I want to search the regex `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` against all columns on every line and output the column index number that had the most regex matches.

for this example `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` would match

```
10.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.1
```

so my desired output would be:

```
2
```

Comment: Why not use pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pandas like this

> `df=pd.read_csv(path, nrows=5000, sep="\t")`

Write a function to check if regex matches.

> ```
> def check_regex_matches(x):
>     
>     return bool(re.match(regex, x))
> ```

Then you can use

> ```
> list_of_bools_where_regex_matches = df["some_col"].apply(lambda
>  x:check_regex_match(x))
>
> df["some_col"][list_of_bools_where_regex_matches].index
> ```

**Note:**
Please check if you require re.match or re.search
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12595082/4213362

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219487/discussion-on-answer-by-vishesh-mangla-python-csv-regex-all-columns-and-output-c).